# Is there any way use -webkit-box-orient property in sharepoint view formatting?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

"-webkit-box-orient":"vertical"  is not working in view formatting

I have used sharepoint online view formatting .

css i have used is below

`"style": { "word-break":"break-word", "-webkit-line-clamp": "10", "height": "201px", "-webkit-box-orient":"vertical", "margin-bottom":"15px" }`

All above is working ,but only "-webkit-box-orient":"vertical"  is not working

Answer (score 0):

The "-webkit-box-orient" property is a CSS property that is specific to the WebKit rendering engine (used by Safari and some other browsers). It's possible that the SharePoint Online view formatting engine doesn't support this property.

please see:http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-box-orient

You might try using the "display: flex" property instead.

There is a post for your reference:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/288120/json-view-formatting-wrap-all-items

Answer (score 0):

Unforutnately, `-webkit-box-orient` CSS property is not supported by SharePoint JSON formatting currently.

However, `-webkit-line-clamp` property is supported currently. Here is the list of all supported CSS properties in SharePoint JSON formatting:

```
'background-color'
'fill'
'background-image'
'border'
'border-bottom'
'border-bottom-color'
'border-bottom-style'
'border-bottom-width'
'border-color'
'border-left'
'border-left-color'
'border-left-style'
'border-left-width'
'border-right'
'border-right-color'
'border-right-style'
'border-right-width'
'border-style'
'border-top'
'border-top-color'
'border-top-style'
'border-top-width'
'border-width'
'outline'
'outline-color'
'outline-style'
'outline-width'
'border-bottom-left-radius'
'border-bottom-right-radius'
'border-radius'
'border-top-left-radius'
'border-top-right-radius'
'box-decoration-break'
'box-shadow'
'box-sizing'

'overflow-x'
'overflow-y'
'overflow-style'
'rotation'
'rotation-point'

'opacity'
'cursor'

'height'
'max-height'
'max-width'
'min-height'
'min-width'
'width'

'flex-grow'
'flex-shrink'
'flex-flow'
'flex-direction'
'flex-wrap'
'flex'
'justify-content'
'align-items'

'box-align'
'box-direction'
'box-flex'
'box-flex-group'
'box-lines'
'box-ordinal-group'
'box-orient'
'box-pack'

'font'
'font-family'
'font-size'
'font-style'
'font-variant'
'font-weight'
'font-size-adjust'
'font-stretch'

'grid-columns'
'grid-rows'

'margin'
'margin-bottom'
'margin-left'
'margin-right'
'margin-top'

'column-count'
'column-fill'
'column-gap'
'column-rule'
'column-rule-color'
'column-rule-style'
'column-rule-width'
'column-span'
'column-width'
'columns'

'padding'
'padding-bottom'
'padding-left'
'padding-right'
'padding-top'

'bottom'
'clear'
'clip'
'display'
'float'
'left'
'overflow'
'position'
'right'
'top'
'visibility'
'z-index'

'border-collapse'
'border-spacing'
'caption-side'
'empty-cells'
'table-layout'

'color'
'direction'
'letter-spacing'
'line-height'
'text-align'
'text-decoration'
'text-indent'
'text-transform'
'unicode-bidi'
'vertical-align'
'white-space'
'word-spacing'
'hanging-punctuation'
'punctuation-trim'
'text-align-last'
'text-justify'
'text-outline'
'text-overflow'
'text-shadow'
'text-wrap'
'word-break'
'word-wrap'

'stroke'
'fill-opacity'

'--inline-editor-border-width'
'--inline-editor-border-style'
'--inline-editor-border-radius'
'--inline-editor-border-color'

'-webkit-line-clamp'

'object-fit'
'transform' // Only translate(arg) and translate(arg, arg) are currently supported
```

**Reference**: [SharePoint JSON formatting syntax reference - style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#style)